# Summation symbol bound problem

Tags: summation, upper-lower-bounds

I am an electrical and electronics engineering student and I am studying signal and systems. We use summation symbol a lot in convolution etc and I am having trouble with my book. In the book it says

[the problem on book here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEo3x.jpg)

it makes the substitution $k = -m$ but in equation(3.62) summation symbol bounds(upper and lower) are not changed. Should not upper bound be $ -\infty $and lower bound be $\infty$. Can you explain please

Comment: I dont think it really matters when you think about what that notation means.... I think they just swapped it and made the upper bound positive and lower bound negative. It wouldn't change the value of the solution.

Comment: So my reasoning is true but as it changes nothing they kept it proper for fourier transformation notation.

Comment: Please typeset your equation using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of [linking images of text](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30184/self-delete-my-criticized-question/30186#30186).